# Problems plotting datetime.timedelta

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to pandas and I was wondering if pandas can plot datetime.timedelta. I tried a few things but here is the current version:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[pd.to_timedelta(total_run_times.values())], index=[0])
plot = df.plot()
fig = plot.get_figure()
fig.savefig("test.png")
```

total_run_times is a dictionary of number: datetime.timedelta. When I print out 'df' in pycharm debugger I get:

```
   0                         1                        2
0  0 days 00:00:06.283421    0 days 00:17:55.295750   0 days 00:00:00
```

Error received:

```
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Versions: python 3.6.3 and pandas 0.20.3

I just want a line graph that plots the times in the array as one line. Can this be done? Or do I have to convert everything to scalar like float?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
-K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transpose your columns to rows with [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html), then convert them to timedelta with [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html)

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.T[0]).plot()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. Just for my understanding of pandas, is the issue the fact that I am using to_timedelta wrong? Or is the problem with my plot() call? (e.g. can't plot my 1x3 df)